# Microsoft.Windows.Shell Namespace equivalent in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon

I am evaluating the code named [Prism 4 MEF Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254120/Prism-4-MEF-Application) It is a .Net 4.0 application and has a reference to [Microsoft.Windows.Shell Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell) which is available if you install [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806375).

However, I am working on .Net 4.5 framework, the ribbon control is somehow added to the framework, I can use it with a reference to DLL and with `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` namespace not `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`

Is there any equivalent control in .net 4.5 and how can I reference it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In .NET 4.5, many of these items are in the [System.Windows.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace, but now live directly in the PresentationFramework.dll assembly.  This can be seen, for example, in the [JumpItem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumpitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation.

If you're working in WPF in .NET 4.5, you should be able to use your existing code *without* adding the extra reference.